# I want to create Drag and Drop UI for Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to make an asp.net page in which you have few controls. You can drag and drop controls to the div and also set the position in the div and save the div in database and recall it whenever you want. I need to know how this will work? How to save the position of controls, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Draggable. It will allow you to create a jQuery UI Placeholder that is the extension of jQuery UI Draggable. This will be stored in the cookie of the browser.

See [jQuery UI — Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) documentation to learn more about it.